# How to convert Column to Row in SFMC Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, cloud

Hi I have the following scenario:
DE 1:

```
JobID  |  CustomerID  |    Link       |
---------------------------------------
 123   |    122       | http://link1  |

 123   |    122       | http://link2  |

 123   |    122       | http://link3  |

 332   |    56        | http://link1  |

 332   |    56        | http://link2  |
```

I would like to get the data from the Data Extension above DE 1 and populate a new Data Extension with the following fields:

DE 2:

```
JobID  |  CustomerID  |    Link1      |   Link 2     |    Link3     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 123   |    122       | http://link1  | http://link2 | http://link3 |

 332   |    56        | http://link1  | http://link2 |              |
```

Is there anyone who have experienced similar task ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the newer T-SQL pivot functions in SFMC, but you can do it this way:

```
select
jobid
, customerid
, max(case when link = 'http://link1' then link else '' end) as Link1
, max(case when link = 'http://link2' then link else '' end) as Link2
, max(case when link = 'http://link3' then link else '' end) as Link3
FROM DE1
group by 
jobid
, customerid
```

**Update**

If you don't want to pick them by value, you can assign a number to each column with a windowing function and use that to pick.  You can change the `order by` to order the rows to whatever fits your criteria for assigning values to the columns.

```
select
 x.jobid
,x.customerid
,max(case when x.num = 1 then link else '' end) as Link1
,max(case when x.num = 2 then link else '' end) as Link2
,max(case when x.num = 3 then link else '' end) as Link3
FROM (
  select
   d.jobid
  ,d.customerid
  ,d.link
  ,row_number() over(partition by d.jobid, d.subscriberkey order by newid()) num
  from de1 d
) as x 
where x.num <= 3
group by 
 x.jobid
,x.customerid
```

Comment: The link `**http://link1, http://link2**` etc. is dynamic and is different for every user, which means I can't predefined the value of "name".  It would be good if I could print the value of the column incrementally.

Comment: Outside of SQL, how would you determine which link goes in which column for a customer?

Comment: With a Script you can do a loop. Get the first link if exist put it in column Link1, get second link put it in column Link2. Is there a way you can do something similar in SQL ?

Comment: That's similar to my second example.  The order by controls the order of the rows by jobid and customerid.

Comment: No this is not solving the problem. Where does "value" come from ? I don't have such a field and you are not able to print column cell value by writing "value".

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part.  Updated my answer.